# Validating all Form.List fields that start with specified name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, antd

First an example. I have data like this

```
{
    phoneNumbers: [
        { number: "123456789", type: "MOBILE" },
        { number: "987654321", type: "HOME" },
    ]
}
```

I can use `Form.List` to go over these fields:

```
<Form.List name="phoneNumbers">
    {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
        {fields.map((field) => (
            <div key={field.key}>
                <Form.Item name="number">...</Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="type">...</Form.Item>
            </div>
        })}
    }
</Form.List>
```

Now, I would like to add a button next each phone number, so that when pressing it, the respective phone number is saved separately. Submitting the form would save all phone numbers. Before, saving a phone number separately, I would like to validate its fields. I can do this:

```
form.validateFields([
    ["phoneNumbers", index, "number"],
    ["phoneNumbers", index, "type"],
])
```

Here I know all the NamePaths as the form is quite simple. However, my form is actually quite a bit more complex and I only know the first element in the NamePath array (here `phoneNumbers`) and the index. I do not know the name of each `Form.Item`. So, let's say I want to validate and save only the second phone number, how can I do that?
I would be perfect if I could do

```
form.validateFields(["phoneNumbers", index])
```

and all `Form.Item`s at this index would be validated, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Your name path in `Form.Item` is not correct. It should be like this `name={[field.name, 'number']}`. Since you just want to validate field i.e. `[field.name, 'number']`, you can first get phoneNumbers list like this: `form.getFieldValue('phoneNumbers')` and then loop over it and call the function that will validate the phone number `phoneNumbers.forEach((item) => validateNumber(item?.number))`.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique The name path definitely is correct. It says from list `phoneNumbers` take item at index X and get field `number`. I have tried it out and it works. You did give me an idea to get the field with `getFieldValue` and then use `Object.keys` to get the field names, however, when I use the `add` method provided by `Form.List`, I need to specify an empty object `{}` as the default value as I do not know the type of the field at that moment. So the `Object.keys` is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are trying validate those validates. Can you please create a code sandbox?